# Establishing an array from foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a form which allows a user to register for multiple events. These are listed in a form with checkboxes (all named `registrations[]` with the event ID as the value) and are submitted as an array.

A subsequent page then loops through each 'checked' event, adding a record to the database for each event:

```
foreach ($_POST['registrations'] as $registration) {

$query="SELECT exhibitions.exhib_id, DATE_FORMAT(exhibitions.exhib_date, %d/%m/%y'), venues.venue_name FROM exhibitions, venues WHERE     exhibitions.venue_id='$registration' AND venues.venue_id='$registration' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$vr=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
$exhib_id=$vr[0];
$exhib_date=$vr[1];
$exhib_venue=$vr[2];

// do database stuff here

}
```

What I need to do is store each `$exhib_date` and `$exhib_venue` in a separate array, which I can reuse later (within a confirmation email, which will list all events the user has registered for).

I thought this would be as simple as establishing a new array **outside** the foreach loop e.g. `$events_attending=array();` and adding elements to the array **within** the foreach loop e.g. `$events_attending['date'] = $exhib_date;` and `$events_attending['venue'] = $exhib_venue;`.

I've tested this minus the foreach loop using `print_r()` and it works fine - so I'm guessing that's where my issue lies?

Can anyone help at all? Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure to sanitize your $_POST!

Answer (score 0):

Other than sanitizing your $_POST data, try:

```
foreach ($_POST['registrations'] as $registration) {

    $query="SELECT exhibitions.exhib_id, DATE_FORMAT(exhibitions.exhib_date, %d/%m/%y'), venues.venue_name FROM exhibitions, venues WHERE     exhibitions.venue_id='$registration' AND venues.venue_id='$registration' LIMIT 1";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $vr=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
    $event[$exhib_id] = array('date' => $vr[1], 'venue' => $vr[2]);

// do database stuff here

}
```

Then you could do a:

```
print_r($event);

Array(
    [1] => Array (
             date => 'event date',
             venue => 'venue'
           )
    [2] => Array (
             date => 'event date',
             venue => 'venue'
           )
```

If you know what event you want, you could call:

```
$event[2]['date'] to get event date, or $event[2]['venue'] for the venue, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$events_attending[] = array( 'date' => $exhib_date, 'venue' => $exhib_venue );
```

This appends your values to the end of the array, as opposed to overwriting them with each loop iteration.

Comment: Hi MrSlayer. Thanks for your help. But when I do a `print_r($events_attending);`, all I'm getting is: 1. Any ideas?!

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is difficult to determine what you are doing incorrectly.  Define `$events_attending = array();` before the loop.  Add the above line inside the loop, at the end.  Then do a `print_r($events_attending);` after the loop is closed.

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I've got. I'm actually testing the output directly in the email which will be sent to users after they have booked event(s). I'm using PHPMailer, but that shouldn't make any difference, should it?

Comment: Not unless something in there is affecting the `$events_attending` variable.  Try eliminating everything that isn't necessary to see if you can figure out where it is failing at.

Comment: Can't see anything that would affect it. `$events_attending[] = array( 'date' => $exhib_date, 'venue' => $exhib_venue );` is the last thing in the loop, then it's straight into the PHPMailer code, followed by `$test = print_r($events_attending);`, then `$msgbody = "Dear ".$name.",<br><br>You've successfully pre-registered for the following exhibitions:<br><br>".$test."<br><br>...` Just can't see what's breaking it. Grrr!

Comment: `print_r` doesn't return the data, it outputs it.  Therefore, $test is being set to the return value, which is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to change these lines

```
$exhib_date=$vr[1];
$exhib_venue=$vr[2];
```

to

```
$exhib_date[]=$vr[1];
$exhib_venue[]=$vr[2];
```

and then you will have two arrays for use later named

```
$exhib_date
$exhib_venue
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your guess, you just missed a small (but big) detail. You'll need to distinguish each row of that array with another identifier of some sort. For example:

```
$events_attending[$exhib_id]['date'] = $exhib_date;
$events_attending[$exhib_id]['venue'] = $exhib_venue;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting the same entry in you array. Try this:

```
$events_attending[] = array('date' => $exhib_date, 'venue' => $exhib_venue);
```

By the way in my opinion you should really use mysql_fetch_assoc() in place of mysql_fetch_array(), it really helps avoiding bugs when your maintain your code.

Oh and yes, be sure to use mysql_real_escape_string() on the POST values you inject in your query, people could do a SQL injection!

Comment: Thanks Simon (and everyone else for similar suggestions!) That looks like it should work. But if I do a `print_r($events_attending)`, the only output I'm getting is: 1. Any ideas?!